# Is it safe to set extfrag_threshold to 1000

Tags: linux, kernel, memory

I am wondering if setting /proc/sys/vm/extfrag_threshold to 1000 is safe?  What are the ramifications of changing this setting.  By default, it is 500.

Does setting it to 1000 essentially disable memory compaction?  Does that mean memory won't get defragmented over time?

I have a situation where memory compaction is hanging the system under low memory conditions and setting extfrag_thres to 1000 stops the hang and improves the performance.  Setting to 990 did NOT help, only setting to 1000 helps.

Comment: I suggest you watch the extfrag/extfrag_index file in debugfs. You should read what the fragmentation index is for each zone and comparing to the extfrag_threshold value, deduce if memory is likely to be compacted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I do think this would disable memory compaction entirely and you could get increased fragmentation over time.  That said, with that disabled, it can still free up RAM through reclaim.  That is, freeing up disk caches, swapping (if you have swap enabled), and unmapping executables (the next time that specific piece of the program runs, it has to load it back in from the executable file on disk.)

Unintuitively (to me at least), this value doesn't really indicate how fragmented the memory is; it just trends toward 0 when the zone gets low enough on free RAM to make it more likely compaction would fail (and has a value of -1.000, or -1000 in extfrag_threshold terms, if there's already free RAM for that size memory allocation).  Disabling compaction could lead to bad performance (for instance, having disk cache repeatedly dropped if you were trying to do use the disk) but I don't think it'll lead to an out of memory condition unless the whole thing truly runs out of memory. So if it's making that particular workload run much better then go for it.